# When I create a docusign template with fields, that if I send it to other people using API the fields disappear?

Tags: asp.net, api, templates, docusignapi

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
        List<string> scopes = new List<string>
        {
            OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE,
            OAuth.Scope_IMPERSONATION
        };
        docuSign_JWT testConfig = new docuSign_JWT();
        testConfig.ApiClient = new ApiClient(testConfig.Host);

        // If this is the first time logging in - Get Consent from the user - this is a onetime step.
        Uri oauthURI = testConfig.ApiClient.GetAuthorizationUri(testConfig.IntegratorKey, scopes, RedirectURI, OAuth.CODE, "testState");
        Process.Start(oauthURI.ToString());
        var privateKeyStream = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(testConfig.PrivateKeyFilename));
        OAuth.OAuthToken tokenInfo = testConfig.ApiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(testConfig.IntegratorKey, testConfig.UserId, testConfig.OAuthBasePath, privateKeyStream, testConfig.ExpiresInHours);
        apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
        apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenInfo.access_token);

        EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        envelopeDefinition.EmailSubject = "Please sign this document";
        envelopeDefinition.TemplateId = "***************";

        DocuSign.eSign.Model.TemplateRole cc1 = new DocuSign.eSign.Model.TemplateRole();
        cc1.Email = "Email1 default template recipient";
        cc1.Name = "Name";
        cc1.RoleName = "Staff";

        DocuSign.eSign.Model.TemplateRole cc2 = new DocuSign.eSign.Model.TemplateRole();
        cc2.Email = "Email2 new email ID";
        cc2.Name = "Name2";
        cc2.RoleName = "Staff";

        DocuSign.eSign.Model.TemplateRole cc3 = new DocuSign.eSign.Model.TemplateRole();
        cc3.Email = "Email3 new Email ID";
        cc3.Name = "Name3";
        cc3.RoleName = "Staff";

       
        List<DocuSign.eSign.Model.TemplateRole> templateRoles = new List<DocuSign.eSign.Model.TemplateRole>();    
        templateRoles.Add(cc1);
        templateRoles.Add(cc2);
        templateRoles.Add(cc3);

        envelopeDefinition.TemplateRoles = templateRoles;
        envelopeDefinition.Status = "sent";

        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountID"], envelopeDefinition);
```

> Above is my code to send docuSign template document. But only default recipient get document with fields, other recipient get only pdf file without fields.
> How to send template document with fields to all recipient.
> below is template fields img
> Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJTtQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all three of your recipients have the same `RoleName`, which means there's going to be an issue mapping each recipient to their role.

Template Role Names should be unique, and their definition in the API call need to match exactly what is present in the template. When setting up roles to be populated by through the API, it's also important to make sure that *only* the RoleName field is filled out. If a template has a "burned in" name and email address, you won't be able to populate them in your API call.

Can you grab a screenshot of how the recipients are set up on the template in the web console? Like this: [image: Template Roles example]

Comment: Hello Drew, Thanks for your reply. I don't want signing order because all fields required to be filled by all the employees. I have a list of employees with same role and I want to send all of them this template document for filling fields and signing. How can I do this?

Comment: @Swap - I'm not sure I understand the use-case here. Typically we would recommend either sending one envelope per recipient, or set up those recipients as a signing group so that only one recipient from the group actually interacts with the envelope. If you genuinely need all three to act on the same envelope and same set of tags, you'll likely need to use Collaborative Fields (https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-collaborative-fields) by setting the `shared` parameter on each tag.

Comment: Hello Drew, My primary need is that I want to add dynamically recipients may be single or multiple. And send them already created template with fields. That fields should be filled by all recipients and submit document. How to fulfill this requirement? Can you please help.