# Failed to add reference to 'DocuSign.eSign'. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component

Tags: asp.net, dll, docusignapi, nuget-package

> while updating package from nuget DocuSign.eSign.dll 5.2.0 to Latest Stable 5.4.0 getting below error

> Failed to add reference to 'DocuSign.eSign'.   Please make sure that
> the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM
> component.
>
> I am using visual studio 2019 with .net framework 4.5.2
> BouncyCastle  1.8.9
> System.ComponentModel.Annotations 5.0
> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 6.11
> Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1
> RestSharp 106.11.7
> Microsoft.CSharp 4.7.0
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols 6.11

Comment: I tried this without issue. I used the VS "Manage NuGet Packages" UI feature, not from commandline. Can you reboot and try again?

Comment: Yes I had tried after  reboot getting same error. My other packages got updated without any issue. Getting this issue only for DocuSign.eSign.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/ can you try to get C# ZIP downloaded from here and see if that works for you?

Comment: Hello Inbar, after download from above link it worked in that project but still unable to update in my project.

Comment: ok, something specific with your project. can you list all the Nuget Packages you have? I can try to repro. Or if you can upload your project and share it I can try to use yours...

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2019 with asp.net webform

.net framework 4.5.2
BouncyCastle 1.8.9
System.ComponentModel.Annotations 5.0
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 6.11
Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1
RestSharp 106.11.7
Microsoft.CSharp 4.7.0
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols 6.11
AjaxControlToolkit 19.1.0
AspNet.ScriptManager.jQ 1.8.2
AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuer 1.8.24
Aspose.PDF 23.3.0
DocuSign.Click 1.0
DocuSign.eSign.dll 5.2.0
DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll 1.7.2
DocuSign.Rooms 1.1

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet 4.3.4
DotNetOpenAuth.Core 4.3.4
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consume 4.3.4
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core 4.3.4
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingPar 4.3.4
EntityFramework 5.0.0
FireSharp 1.1.0
FireSharp.Serialization.JsonNet 1.1.0
iTextSharp 5.5.13.1
jQuery 1.8.2
jQuery.UI.Combined 1.8.24
Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls 1.0.0
Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls 1.0.0
Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth  1.0.1
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 6.11.0
WebGrease 1.1.0

Comment: Can you try to remove DocuSign.eSign.dll and use the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DocuSign.DocuSignVSExtension DS extension to add it back in?

Comment: I had removed DocuSign.eSign.dll and use the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DocuSign.DocuSignVSExtension, but this is also version 5.2.0

Comment: As mentioned in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DocuSign.DocuSignVSExtension this documentation I configured in existing project step 9 not occurred. Also DocuSign folder is not created and add code example  menu not available.

Comment: Is there any chance you can send me your project?

Comment: Sorry but I cant share project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, I can reproduce. We will be working on it and I'll update when we have a fix.

**UPDATE:** this has been fixed with a new release today of https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/5.4.1

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try with upgrade .Net Framework to 5.0. But Still it will be helpful if you update when fix the bug.

Comment: Referencing to this question I have a question that because of DocuSign.eSign.dll 5.2.0 I am not getting JWT refresh token function in package ? Or Why I am not getting JWT refresh token function in package/metadata?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are you saying the dll is missing some code or that you are using it and it's not working?

Comment: Yes I can get access_token from API Client -RequestJWTUserToken, create template, send envelop, etc. But now I want to refresh token but RefreshToekn function is missing in dll code. Dont know I am wrong or missing something. Please help for this.

Comment: For JWT there's no refresh token, you can just get a new one every time the same way you do the first time, there's no need for refresh token, they serve no purpose with JWT

Comment: Hello Inbar, Thanks for your response. Need another help Can you please its urgent. Getting problem while sending template document for multiple recipients. Below is question link. Thank you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67430136/when-i-create-a-docusign-template-with-fields-that-if-i-send-it-to-other-people