# DocuSign.eSign.dll nuget package 5.4.0 has no available namespaces

Tags: docusignapi

Went into Nuget and updated from 5.2.0 to 5.4.0 and all of my using statements for DocuSign stopped working. No namespaces are found in 5.4.0 but if I revert back everything works again.

Tried with my project and even a new project created with the DocuSign Extension.

.NET Framework 4.8
Visual Studio 2019 16.9.5

Comment: Root cause the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67457209/failed-to-add-reference-to-docusign-esign-please-make-sure-that-the-file-is-a?noredirect=1#comment119333457_67457209

Comment: Thank you. I saw that post earlier and wasn't sure if it was the same exact problem but it was promising that someone was having a similar problem.  Odd that this version has been out for a bit and no reports of this issue.

Comment: If you can use .NET 5.0 - that problem goes away. I'm asking to get this fixed ASAP, but will be next week at the earliest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed with 5.4.1 which you can find here - https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/5.4.1

Thanks for bringing this to our attention!